# Unhandled Runtime Error. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, next.js, frontend

I'm using next.js 14 and I'm trying to merge 2 pdf files based on their contents. However, when I try to read the content of the pdf file using **const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(content).promise;**, I got the error **Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: [object Promise]. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function.** Can anyone help me solve this? I dont even use lasy elemnt. Thanks in advance!

page.tsx:

```
import PDFFileMerger from "@/components/PDFFileMerger";
import Image from "next/image";
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <main className="overflow-hidden">
      <PDFFileMerger />
    </main>
  );
}
```

PDFFileMerger.tsx:

```
"use client";

import React, { useState, ChangeEvent, useEffect } from 'react';
import { PDFDocument, rgb } from 'pdf-lib';
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';

function PDFFileMerger() {

  const [file1, setFile1] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [file2, setFile2] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [mergedPdf, setMergedPdf] = useState<Uint8Array | null>(null);
  const [textOutput, setTextOutput] = useState<string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!file1) return;


    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = async function() {
      const content = this.result;
      if (content) {
        try {
          const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(content).promise;
          console.log(pdf);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error loading PDF:', error);
        }
      }
    };

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file1);

  }, [file1] );

  const handleFile1Change = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const selectedFile = event.target.files?.[0];
    setFile1(selectedFile || null);
  };

 return (
    <div>
      <input id="pdf1" type="file" accept=".pdf" onChange={handleFile1Change} />
      <input type="file" accept=".pdf" onChange={handleFile2Change} />
      <button onClick={handleMerge}>Merge PDFs</button>
      {mergedPdf && (
      <a
        href={URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([mergedPdf], { type: 'application/pdf' }))}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        download="merged.pdf"
      >
        Open Merged PDF
      </a>
    )}
    <div id="textOutput">{textOutput}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PDFFileMerger;
```

I tried to use with and without useEffect(), and adding async, await, etc... . But the error still occurs whenever I have the line **const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(content).promise;**